# Non stationary solutions of the PDE $u_t + u_x = u_{xx}$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, uniform-convergence

> **Problem.** Consider the PDE 
>   $$
> u_t + u_x = u_{xx}, \qquad (t,x) \in (0,+\infty) \times (0,1).
> $$
>
> (i) Write the unique solution $\overline{u}=\overline{u}(x)$ which does not depend on time and is of class $C^2([0,1])$ satisfying $u(0)=1$, $u(1)=0$.
>
> (ii) Show that all other solutions $u=u(t,x) \in C^2([0,+\infty) \times [0,1])$ with $u(t,0)=1$ and $u(t,1)=0$ converge to $\overline{u}$ in the $C^0$ norm as $t \to +\infty$.

Part (i) is indeed very easy: since $\overline{u}$ is independent on time, we have to solve the boundary value problem 
$$
\begin{cases}
u^{\prime\prime} - u^\prime = 0\\
u(0)=1 \\
u(1)=0
\end{cases}
$$
whose solution is 
$$
\overline{u}(x) = \frac{e}{e-1} - \frac{1}{e-1}e^x. 
$$

Now I do not know how to solve point (ii). I have tried a change of variables $(t,x) \mapsto (t^\prime, y)$: in particular, setting $y=x-t$ and $t^\prime=t$ I have obtained a heat equation $u_t - u_{yy}=0$ but I do not know how to handle the boundary conditions. I think there is something hidden in the text that I cannot see... Could you help me, please?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the $C^0$ norm?

Comment: I suppose it means the uniform norm (also called the sup norm).

Comment: The first step would be to introduce $v=u-\bar u$, which solves the same PDE with homogeneous boundary condition. Using the energy method, one can show $v\to 0$ in $L^2$ norm: $$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^1 v^2\,dx =-2\int_0^1 u_x^2\,dx \le -2\pi^2 \int_0^1 u^2\,dx$$ (using the PDE, integration by parts, boundary condition, and Wirtinger's inequality).   I don't see an easy way to get $C^0$ convergence from here, though...

Comment: @900sit-upsaday Many thanks for your useful comment. I did not know Wirtinger's inequality, it is a nice tool to keep in mind. By the way, the exercise has been given as a problem for the admission to a PhD program: it should not be too hard, but I still do not know how to get it... Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried finding a solution for $v$ in terms of a Fourier sine series? (The usual "separation of variables" method.)